# LWC: Getting error while testing with validity object using lwc-jest

Tags: unit-test, lightning-web-components

I am trying to write test case on my blur event(using `lwc-jest`), which is working fine, till I am not adding my custom validation method: `setValidity` in my component, which getting called on blur and having switch case:

```
export function setValidity(self) {
    const element = self.template.querySelector('[id=' + self.id + ']');
    const validity = element.validity;

    const messageWhenBadInput = 'This field is not valid.';
    const messageWhenValueMissing = 'Required field';
    const messageWhenPatternMismatch = 'Your pattern does not match, Please check.';
     ...

    switch (true) {
        case validity.valid:
            self.errorMessage = '';
            break;
        case validity.valueMissing:
            self.errorMessage = messageWhenValueMissing;
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

here, It's not getting validity object(which is undefined). So it's throwing error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined

[image: error with validation]

Please suggest, how can I handle this.

Comment: The validity field is `undefined` on `element`. Make sure the element is the right object you expect. By the way, using the global `id` attribute is changed at runtime by the LWC engine to ensure the Shadow DOM encapsulation. You should not use `id` to reference DOM elements in LWC. I think the issue comes from here.

Comment: @pmdartus, I have already changed id with other custom attribute.. Still same.

But it's working perfectly fine with component UI.... Only issue with unit test case.

Comment: This is probably a gap in jsdom. It appears that it has been recently implemented in jsdom: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/pull/2142. The version of jsdom used by jest is quite old. You should consider manually polyfilling this API for now until the version of jsdom is updated in jest.

Comment: jsdom is there in Jest. But I put one hack and it's working for me. Added 

`if(!validity) { return; }` before switch case.